# Dell XPS 9530 touchscreen not working on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, touchscreen

I had it working on my previous Ubuntu 16.04 installation, but I can't remember how I made it work (and if I did anything to make it work).

- `lsusb` gives me:

  ```
  Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:0ac3 Synaptics, Inc. Synaptics Large Touch Screen
  ```
- `xinput list` gives me:

  ```
  ⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
  ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ Logitech M325                              id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen Mouse   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                 id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ```
- `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` has:

  ```
  Section "InputClass"
           Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
           MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
           MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
           Driver "libinput"
  EndSection
  ```
- I have `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` installed.
- I ran `xinput_calibrator` but it's not responding to my touch.

What am I missing?

Comment: Works out of the box on a fresh installation, also in 20.04. Remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and install xserver-xorg-input-libinput instead.

Comment: I am in the same boat with a XPS 9333 (purchased 2014). I have been upgrading regularly and I think it's only broken since 20.04.